# how to get in li>span 2nd Div text..?

Tags: jquery, html, list, text, get

```
<ul id="LivePlayList" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" tabindex="0" style="width: 1025px; top: 50px; left: 51px;">

    <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width:100%;height:25px;">
        <span style="width:100%;height:25px;display:flex;">
        <div id="ui-id-2" style="position: absolute;right:10px;margin-top: 2px" tabindex="-1">Qudosh Idto ܩܘܕܫ ܥܕܬܐ</div>
        <div style="display:none;">2</div>
        <div style="left:10px;position: absolute;margin-top: 2px;">Qudosh Idto qwdsch ʿdt</div>
        </span>
     </li>

</ul>
```

How to get 2nd div text on click ul li span

```
$("#LivePlayList").on('click','span',function (){

});
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#LivePlayList").on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log($(this).find("div:nth-child(2)").text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="LivePlayList" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" tabindex="0" style="width: 1025px; top: 50px; left: 51px;">

  <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width:100%;height:25px;">
    <span style="width:100%;height:25px;display:flex;">
        <div id="ui-id-2" style="position: absolute;right:10px;margin-top: 2px" tabindex="-1">Qudosh Idto ܩܘܕܫ ܥܕܬܐ</div>
        <div style="display:none;">2</div>
        <div style="left:10px;position: absolute;margin-top: 2px;">Qudosh Idto qwdsch ʿdt</div>
        </span>
  </li>

</ul>
How to get 2nd div text on click ul li span
```

1. Use `.find()`
2. To get second div use `:nth-child(2)` index starts at 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` and then combine it with `:eq(x)` where x is the number of the div you want (starting at 0)

`$(this).find("div:eq(1)")`

```js
$("#LivePlayList").on('click', 'span', function() {
  console.log($(this).find("div:eq(1)").text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="LivePlayList" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" tabindex="0" style="width: 1025px; top: 50px; left: 51px;">

  <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width:100%;height:25px;">
    <span style="width:100%;height:25px;display:flex;">
        <div id="ui-id-2" style="position: absolute;right:10px;margin-top: 2px" tabindex="-1">Qudosh Idto ܩܘܕܫ ܥܕܬܐ</div>
        <div style="display:none;">2</div>
        <div style="left:10px;position: absolute;margin-top: 2px;">Qudosh Idto qwdsch ʿdt</div>
    </span>
  </li>

</ul>
```